# how to implements change "int" value when using the extension method in c#

Tags: c#

Recently, I met a problem that how to change "int" value when using the extension method, don't allow use keyword "ref" or "out":

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var a = 5;
     var b = 6;
     a.Swap(b);
     Console.WriteLine("a={0},b={1}", a, b);
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I want to implement the Swap method(exchange variable a and variable b) and final output like this:

> a = 6，b = 5

Swap method needs to exchange variable a and variable b, The issue is assigned by my teacher.

My answer is :

```
unsafe static void Swap(this int a, int b)
  {
      int* pb = &b;
      pb += 7;
      int* pa = &a;
      pa += 8;
      int temp = *pa;
      *pa = *pb;
      *pb = temp;
  }
```

But my teacher said it not good enough. Because the 7 and 8 will be affected by the C# compiler.

I really didn't know how to implements Swap method. I think the integer will be passed by value when passing into Swap, and can't change it unless finding out its original address.

Did I misunderstand something?  Your thought would be appreciated.

---

added:

There is a lot of people said it doesn't make sense, and a lot of questions, I know it doesn't make sense. but it truly can do this. I will paste the answer to bellow after I got the answer from my teacher.

---

added 20190225

I get an answer from my teacher, below is the complete answer:

```
   internal static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var (a, b) = (5,6);
        a.Swap(b);
        Console.WriteLine($"a=({a}),b=({b})");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Swap<T>(ref this T op1, in T op2)
        where T : struct
    {
        var temp = op1;
        op1 = op2;
        RefUnlocker.Unlock(op2) = temp;
    }
}
public class RefUnlocker
{
    private delegate ref T InToRef<T>(in T arg) where T : struct;

    private static ref T RefWrapper<T>(ref T arg) where T : struct => ref arg;

    private static readonly MethodInfo _refWrapper = typeof(RefUnlocker)
        .GetMethod(nameof(RefWrapper), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    public static ref T Unlock<T>(in T arg) where T : struct
    {
        Delegate dgt = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(InToRef<T>), _refWrapper.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)));

        InToRef<T> itrf = (InToRef<T>)dgt;

        return ref itrf(arg);
    }
}
```

C# 7.2 provides a keyword in. The in modifier on parameters, to specify that an argument is passed by reference but not modified by the called method. Adding the in modifier to an argument is a source compatible change.

However you can use Delegate to modify the in parameter.

Thanks to my teacher deeply for this.

Comment: Just pass them by ref, and ditch the pointers. however its unclear what you want or are trying to do

Comment: Also this makes no sense *"Because the 7 and 8 will be affected by the C# compiler"*

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear, I have modified the question. Swap method needs to exchange variable a and variable b, and can't allowed use keyword "ref" and "out".

Comment: Does this need to be an extension method?

Comment: The extension method is not necessary.

Comment: I'm still curious about what the 7 and 8 represent.  Are you thinking those will be optimized out by the C# compiler?

Comment: the 7 and 8 is the memory address difference. difference compiler will product different address difference.

Comment: @V.Wu That makes zero sense.  I don't think there's any guarantee on the shape of the memory allocated.  It seems like your teacher is trying to "speed" something up that is already lightning fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not at all clear why you are adding 7 and 8 to some pointers.
What do you hope to accomplish with that?

If the extension method is not essential, then the answer is easy!!
As Michael Randall wrote:

```
static unsafe void Swap(int* pa, int* pb)
{
    int temp = *pb;
    *pb = *pa;
    *pa = temp;
}

// Call this with: Swap(&a,&b);
```

---

The best I could do with an extension is:

```
using System;

public static class Test
{
    static unsafe void Swap(this int a, int* pa, int* pb)
    {
        *pa = *pb;
        *pb = a;
    }

    public static unsafe void Main()
    {
     var a = 5;
     var b = 6;
     a.Swap(&a, &b);
     Console.WriteLine("a={0},b={1}", a, b);
    }
}
```

[IDEOne Code](https://ideone.com/yNeVPw)

### Results

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0.01s 131520KB
a=6,b=5
```

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear, I have modified the question. Swap method needs to exchange variable a and variable b, and can't allowed use keyword "ref" and "out"

Comment: You were perfectly clear.  I just do not believe that is possible in C#.

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I posted the complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is only to back up [@abelenky's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34824/abelenky) answer, not to be an answer in itself

Just with pointers, no extension, no `ref`, no `out`

```
public unsafe static void Swap(int* a, int* b)
{
   var temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
}
```

**Usage**

```
public unsafe static void  Main()
{
   var a = 5;
   var b = 6;
   Swap(&a, &b);
   Console.WriteLine("a={0},b={1}", a, b);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

or another variation with a franken-extensions

```
public static unsafe class ext
{
   public static int Swap(this int a, int* b)
   {
      var temp = *b;
      *b = a;
      return temp;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var a = 5;
var b = 6;
a = a.Swap(&b);
Console.WriteLine("a={0},b={1}", a, b);
```

Comment: Your Swap method mismatched, you must use it like :
a.Swap(b);

Comment: I agree, this is the best answer, but the question seemed to call for an Extension method, so I hacked one in, against my better judgement. :)  The only thing the extension gets you is avoiding the `temp` variable.

Comment: I posted the complete answer